# How do I make proportional Circles plot in R

Tags: r, comparison, area

I've been looking for a package or a way to make proportional cirles (did I miss something in ggplot?), maybe even interactive like `plotly` package. But I couldn't find any at all. I found only proportional circles to map but that's not what I want, and I also want to avoid using many variables such as radius, center positions etc.
Just proportional size visualization. Any idea?
`packcircles` doesn't fit though.

[image: I want something like that (I could do it in tableau but meh.)]

Comment: What's wrong with `packcircles`, sounds like exactly what you're looking for. No, you didn't miss anything in ggplot. Something like this doesn't really fit into the Grammar of Graphics. (I'm just imagining `aes(x = "doesn't matter", y = "whatever works"...)`)

Comment: https://github.com/jcheng5/bubbles

Comment: That was the library I was looking for. If it's not much of an issue, is there any kind of interactive package or only this one?

For gregor, the `packcircles` needs too much data, circle size, center position bla bla bla.